# Setting "Restore system settings and previous versions of files" option

Tags: powershell, windows-7, setting, system-restore

Using the command prompt or Windows Powershell of Windows 7 SP1, how can I set the option "Restore system settings and previous versions of files" for the creation of restore points?

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following command in a PowerShell console to get a list of commands related to restore points:

```
Get-Command -Noun *computer* | Format-Table Name, PSSnapin
```

Checkpoint-Computer

Disable-ComputerRestore

Enable-ComputerRestore

Get-ComputerRestorePoint